# How to make a counter strike source server that only allow a specific weapon to use?

Tags: mods, counter-strike, hosting, counter-strike-source

How to make a counter strike source server that prevent users' from buying any weapon or anything, just give them a specific weapon that used by the all players ?

Comment: the easiest option would be to use custom maps, for example `aim_map` only has M4 and AK, `aim_deagle` only gives players Desert Eagles, `awp_` maps only have AWP, `ka_` maps are knife-only, `he_` maps are grenades-only and so on

Answer (score 1):

Without plugins the best way to disable weapons in general is to do the following:

1. go to the `cstrike/scripts/` directory of your server
2. rename or move all `weapon_xy.ctx` files of the weapons you do not wish to be used
3. If the server complains about file consistency you might have to disable `sv_pure`, but it should be fine as-is.

Disclaimer:
This will make the weapon unusable, but people will still be charged money for trying to buy them. Also the removed weapons will be disabled globally on all maps.

Usually it is easier to use plugins for this, like Mattie Eventscripts or Mani Admin (where you can disable weapons in config files), but this is how you do it without them.